# pdflatex: builtin glyph names is empty

Tags: symbols

I'm new to Windows and just installed MikTex with TeXMaker.
I just tried to compile a pretty large file using pdflatex and get the following error in the log:

"!pdfTeX error: pdflatex: builtin glyph names is empty

==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!"

While it perfectly works under Ubuntu, I have no idea of what's happening here.

The only red line I got in the log (which is too big to be given here :-() is

"Package babel Info: Making ! an active character on input line 432."

I have no more information. I can compile all the other files; using a console does not help. I removed an re-installed everything; my installation is up to date.

Any help is welcome...

Here is my header (just in case) :

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage[cyr]{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{dictsym}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]% activate with a name prefix
% pdflatex -shell-escape an
%
\def\thickness{thick}
```

Comment: you will have to add a small document body to your example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The problem is dictsym, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/630746/2388 for a work-around.

Comment: Yes, the problem was disctsym. I added pigpen as suggested in the link and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: A better fix is probably to add `\pdfmapline{dictsym DictSym <dictsym.pfb}` (and for pigpen `\pdfmapline{pigpen <pigpen.pfa}`  to your document. Then you don't destroy the tounicode settings which would affect copy&paste.

Comment: Yes I see; thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, when I'm doing so, some lower size fonts are not well generated and seem to be unavailable.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the equal signs. They should be directly after the {

Comment: Yes! It worked. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
\pdfmapline{=dictsym DictSym <dictsym.pfb}
\pdfmapline{=pigpen <pigpen.pfa}
```

to your document. This will overwrite and correct the original map lines.

Comment: Does the `=` selectively disable the glyph to unicode mapping?