# Errors using the pigpen package

Tags: errors, packages

As usual I feel like it's a really stupid question but I can't seem to find an answer to it...

I want to write a short text (2 or 3 sentences at most) in the pigpen cipher. So I tried using the pigpen package and when I try to compile and visualize... I get nothing except a message saying the process ended with one or more errors.

Here's a Minimal Non-Working Exemple :

```
    \documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{pigpen}


\begin{document}
    
{\pigpenfont M}
\end{document}
```

any idea why it doesn't work ? Is the package obsolete ? I found no mention of that but it dates back to 2008... I'm really stuck on this one...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: eek `!pdfTeX error: pdflatex: builtin glyph names is empty`

Comment: it works in texlive 2020 but not 2021-2023

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately it doesn't actually work with `pdflatex`.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634975/2388 (if pdflatex is used)

Comment: what's changed since 2020?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle we added `\pdfgentounicode=1 ` https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60195236#60195236

Comment: ah..............

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it works ! Thanks a lot ! Is it possible to accept your comment as an answer ? Sorry I'm still new here ^^;

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  yes definitely !