# glyphtounicode incompatible fonts with TeX Live 2021 and later: What does = do in \pdfmapline? What difference does subsetting make?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, errors, texlive, unicode

The following MNWE fails with TeX Live 2021 onwards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dictsym}
\begin{document}
  \dsbiological
\end{document}
```

Compilation ends with

```
<</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/dictsym/dictsym.pfb>>
    !pdfTeX error: pdflatex: builtin glyph names is empty
     ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

According to [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/630746/), this is because TL 2021 and later adds a glyphtounicode mapping by default, but `dictsym` is incompatible with this. His workaround involved disabling the mapping globally, but [Ulrike Fischer's answer to a later question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634975/) suggested that adding

```
\pdfmapline{=dictsym DictSym <dictsym.pfb}
```

be used instead to 'overwrite and correct the original map lines'. And, indeed, the following MWE works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dictsym}
\pdfmapline{=dictsym DictSym <dictsym.pfb}
\begin{document}
  \dsbiological
\end{document}
```

This changes the original map line in two ways.

1. An `=` is added at the start (if this survives `\pdfmapline`).
2. `<` replaces `<<` so pdfTeX will embed only a subset of the font rather than the whole thing.

But I am curious about the `=`, which I could not find documented in pdfTeX's documentation, where the syntax of map file lines is explained. Note that the following MWE also compiles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dictsym}
\pdfmapline{dictsym DictSym <dictsym.pfb}
\begin{document}
  \dsbiological
\end{document}
```

Basic testing suggests that it is the change from `<<` to `<` which makes the difference. While both

```
\pdfmapline{dictsym DictSym <dictsym.pfb}
```

and

```
\pdfmapline{=dictsym DictSym <dictsym.pfb}
```

work, neither

```
\pdfmapline{=dictsym DictSym <<dictsym.pfb}
```

nor the original

```
\pdfmapline{dictsym DictSym <<dictsym.pfb}
```

do.

According to [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615300/pdflatex-builtin-glyph-names-is-empty/634975#comment1582600_615300), omitting the equals may cause subtler problems, but the use of `=` isn't common in map files, as far as I've seen. (Perhaps it is specific to `\pdfmapline`?)

But further testing suggests the `=` is crucial after all. In some cases I get the same compilation error unless I include this change as well.

So, I'm puzzled on two counts.

1. What exactly does the additional `=` do?
2. How does embedding the entire font versus embedding only a subset interact with the glyphtounicode mapping?

In some cases (if `scaled` is not used?) the following works, too.

```
\usepackage{dictsym}
\font\f=dictsym
\pdfnobuiltintounicode \f
```

but this can't be how I should be using it as it fails otherwise. (I just thought it would be nice to have a transparent workaround.)

---

Detailed output for MNWE:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./prawf.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dictsym/dictsym.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upsy.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./prawf.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdft
ex.map}] (./prawf.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/
amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/d
ictsym/dictsym.pfb>>
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex: builtin glyph names is empty
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: The = is described in the pdftex manual. Search for the syntax of pdfmapfile and pdfmapline (around page28 or so). If means that the new entry replaces an existing one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer should I update that old answer with a pdfmapline version do you think?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle imho simply replacing the map line is the best (and we should perhaps ask Karl if that can't be done directly for the two problematic fonts.)

Comment: I have mailed the package authors (and Karl)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank-you. I was looking at the syntax for lines in 5.1.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks.

Comment: What's the connection between subsetting and glyphtounicode? I don't understand why changing to subsetting works.

Comment: @cfr pigpen has been updated  and submitted to ctan

Comment: @cfr see Marcel's comment here https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60195236#60195236

Comment: Thanks! May I ask how you find these things in chat so long afterwards? I can't find a way to track things down even when I know they're there. I guess the changing the map file didn't happen quite yet? ;)